# How to split a dataframe of values and use rle on the chunks?

Tags: r, list, split, run-length-encoding

I am trying to divide up (not necessarily into even chunks, bc the real data may vary) a single column of integers called scores (.csv file) and then count the consecutive values (of x chosen value, e.g. 1) in each divided portion or the mean length of a consecutive value. All possible with rle.

I can easily split the column of integers using split however this is seemingly incompatible with rle (presumably bc split generates a list). I looked for solutions and/or alternatives to rle but didn't come up with anything.

Example Scores

```
scores <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Split them

```
g <- seq_along(scores)

scores.div <- split(scores, ceiling(g/7))
```

Example of what I tried, but didn't work

```
Scores.rle <- sapply(scores.div, function(x) {
  r <- rle(x)
  sum(r$values == 1)
})
```

I'd expect some output like this:

2 2 0 1 1

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The output seems as you expect. Call `unname(Scores.rle)` to remove the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could also use `tapply`

```
as.vector(tapply(scores, ceiling(g/7), FUN = function(x) sum(rle(x)$values == 1)))
#[1] 2 2 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and your code work well.

```
> scores <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
> g <- seq_along(scores)
> scores.div <- split(scores, ceiling(g/7))
> Scores.rle <- sapply(scores.div, function(x) {
+   r <- rle(x)
+   sum(r$values == 1)
+ })
> Scores.rle
1 2 3 4 5 
2 2 0 1 1
```

and my session is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/lapply), `sapply` returns a named vector, according to the names for list created by `lapply`:

> `sapply` is a user-friendly version and wrapper of `lapply` by default returning a vector, matrix or, if `simplify = "array"`, an array if appropriate, by applying `simplify2array()`. `sapply(x, f, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)` is the same as `lapply(x, f)`

simply `unname` it (see its [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/unname)) and you're done:

```
> scores <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
> g <- seq_along(scores)
> scores.div <- split(scores, ceiling(g/7))
> unname(sapply(scores.div, function(x) sum(rle(x)$values ==1)))
[1] 2 2 0 1 1
```